# Inject parameterBagInterface in nested service

Tags: php, oop, symfony5

I have a SearchManager service which can execute search with the specified engine.

```php
// controller

public function searchAction(RequestStack $requestStack, SearchManager $searchManager): Response
{
    // code

    $engine = new ElasticsearchEngine();
    $searchManager->setEngine($engine)->search($requestStack);
    // code
}

class SearchManager {

    private $engine;

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function setEngine(EngineInterface $engine)
    {
        $this->engine = $engine;
        return $this->engine;
    }
}

class ElasticsearchEngine implement EngineInterface 
{
    public function search(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        // Here I build the request
        $elasticsearchCommand['from'] = 0;
        $elasticsearchCommand['size'] = 100;
        $elasticsearchCommand['query']['bool']['must'] = ["match_all" => new \stdClass()];
        // so on
        // To continue building the query I need to parse posted data and get elasticsearch formatted query so I use a class to do that
        $formParser = new FormParser($requestStack);
        $elasticsearchCommand['query']['bool']['filter']['bool']['filter'] = $formParser->getFormattedQuery();
    }
}
```

In FormParser I need for some reasons some app parameter. But all these class are instantiate explicitly and I can't get benefits from auto wiring. How can access ParameterbarInterface without injecting it where it's not needed ? (cascading injection)

Comment: You can't. If you need the ParameterBag in FormParser, you need to inject it somehow. If you are instantiating it manually instead of getting if from the container, then you'll have to inject it in the service that instantiates FormParser.

Comment: What's `FormParser` anyway? Is it your code? Why can't you create a service that needs `RequestStack` and `ParamterBagInterface`, and inject **that** into `EngineInterface`?

Comment: Yes FormParser is my own service that build query depending on the engine

Comment: So just make the service depend on `RequestStack` and `ParameterBagInterface`, and get it from the container instead of instantiating it manually. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Get it from controller then inject it into `ElasticsearchEngine` ?

Comment: No, use autowiring as with any other service. `FormParser` would depend on `RequestStack` and `ParameterBagInterface`, and `ElasticsearchEngine` would in turn depend on `FormParser`. And `ElasticsearchEngine` shouldn't be instantiated manually either, but get it via autowiring as well.

Comment: `ElasticsearchEngine` should be instantiated manually because engine could be another kind like `MysqlEngine` no ? Because `SearchEngineManager` need an instance of `EngineInterface`

Comment: thx but all provided links not helping me

Comment: They will, once you take some time to understand they apply specifically to your issue. You need to create several services that need to be autowired, and not instantiate them manually.

Comment: no they won't, in controller `searchAction(EngineInterface $engine)`Symfony not knows if `ElasticsearchEngine` or `MysqlEngine` or `WhateverEngine` should be instantiate

Comment: Exactly, which is why the linked dupes show you how to inject a group of closely related services.